# Extract String Date from xml data via python

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping

I am trying to learn some example. I can extract data from xml tags, but I am facing problem to extract Date value which is string. xml data looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ValCurs Date="20.04.2016" name="Official exchange rate">
   <Valute ID="47">
   <NumCode>978</NumCode>
   <CharCode>EUR</CharCode>
   <Nominal>1</Nominal>
   <Name>Euro</Name>
   <Value>22.4023</Value>
 </Valute>
 <Valute ID="44">
      <NumCode>840</NumCode>
      <CharCode>USD</CharCode>
      <Nominal>1</Nominal>
      <Name>US Dollar</Name>
      <Value>19.7707</Value>
  </Valute>
```

I am trying to extract Date value which is '20.04.2016' and later I want to add this to a list. the code I use to extract the data in tags is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import webbrowser
import requests
import sys
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict


url = 'https://www.bnm.md/en/official_exchange_rates?get_xml=1&date=20.04.2016'
session = requests.session()
response = session.get(url)
data = ET.fromstring(response.content)
elements = []
for element in data.iter():
    if element.tag in ('Name', 'Value'):
        elements.append(element.text)
     print elements
```

Can someone guide me how to extract Date string value which is "20.04.2016". Thanks

Comment: In XML, `x="y"` in a tag is called an *attribute*, use that for googling.

Comment: @AlexHall thanks a lot for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said: *"but I am facing problem to extract Date value which is string and it has no tag."* - That's not true!

The `Date` value is an attribute of the `<ValCurs>` tag.

So using a xml parser like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), you access the `ValCurs` tag to get the `Date` value.

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.bnm.md/en/official_exchange_rates?get_xml=1&date=20.04.2016'

html_source = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'lxml')

val_tag = soup.find_all('valcurs')

for val in val_tag:
    print(val['date'])
```

**Output:**

```
'20.04.2016'
```

Comment: but s in BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml') is not define in my xml data format

Comment: @robbin I've updated my answer to fetch the information from the website you provided, instead of assigning the xml content you provided to a variable called `s`. Take a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will give it a try.

Comment: Can you modify it according to my code. I am using a bit different code than yours and I am new to coding that why I am unable to modify your code in mine. I would be thankful.

Comment: I couldn't understand what you said... My code provides the Date value that you were trying to scrape. What else do you need?

Comment: the code in my question parse xml data a little bit different.   'session = requests.session()
response = session.get(url)
data = ET.fromstring(response.content)'   . .   so in soup = BeautifulSoupdata, 'lxml') should be given, but it is not working. I simply mean my code is a litte bit different while parsing xml data.

Comment: Instead of `data` in `soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')`, try using `soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')` or `soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')`. Your code isn't working because when you load `data`, you're parsing an `Element`, not some `text`, since according to [ElementTree Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring), the method `fromstring()` returns an [Element Instance](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element).

Comment: now It is working fine and I can get the date attribute. Thanks for the help. hav a nice time.

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help you. You're welcome! :)